# How to save values in appsettings.json fetched from UI display

Tags: c#, extjs

For UI, I am using Extjs, for server side, C#. My problem is i have a appsettings.json property under HubSettings, LiveStream is the property and it has Url, and title. I need to fetch Url and Title from UI and update in appsettings.json. How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

appsettings.json cannot be written to. You may want to use localStorage.